# ssd not recognized by windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb, ssd, external-hard-drive

So I recently got a [2.5" 500GB SATA3 SSD (Crucial MX200)](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820148949&Tpk=20-148-949) and a [USB 3.0 to 2.5" SATA3 adapter](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812186219&Tpk=12-186-219). When I try plugging the SSD into my laptop via USB3 I'd expect the drive to show up in Disk Management in the Control Panel in Windows 7. Even if it's not formatted I'd still expect it to show up but it isn't.

I tried the USB 3.0 to 2.5" SATA3 adapter on a 500GB SATA3 HDD and it read that one just fine - it's just not reading the SSD.

Could my SSD be bad? It's brand new..

Comment: it's possible that the SSD is bad. I would personally contact crucial about a replacement

Comment: Honestly.  I suspect the adapter if anything.  If you connect the drive over a SATA connection is it visible?

Comment: There you go @Ramhound, you just taught me something :D

Comment: If the adapter works with a HDD it should work with the SSD.

Answer (score 0):

Consider placing an RMA request and get your SSD replaced. It's the SSD that is bad and probably shipped faulty.

Answer (score 0):

if you have access to an linux computer / or are able to boot a linux live system from usb-stick or dvd try if it shows up with this -
i had problems with windows7 and an unformatted SSD.
i then formated it with linux - after this windows could use / reformat the disc.
(so for me it seams windows has sometimes problems to find the SSD if it is not formated.)